# Two Array's Trying to Combine where A Value is equal to a key?

Tags: php, arrays

I Have Two Array's One That is a 'App' Array and one is a 'Table' Array. Each Row in 'Table' has an 'AppID' As Shown Below. How can I combine  the array to where the App_ID in the Tables Array is under the Same App_ID on the App Array? What I Currently Have is First and Want I Want is after that. I am using PHP. Thank Your for all of the Help!

App Array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [App_ID] => 1
            [App_Name] => Project Manager
            [App_Created] => 2014-12-17 16:31:57
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [App_ID] => 2
            [App_Name] => Estimating
            [App_Created] => 2014-12-17 23:49:40
        )
)
```

Tables Array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Table_ID] => 1
            [App_ID] => 1
            [Table_Name] => Customers
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Table_ID] => 2
            [App_ID] => 1
            [Table_Name] => Jobs
        )

)
```

I Want to Go to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [App_ID] => 1
            [App_Name] => Kennedy_Fabricating_Project_Manager
            [App_Created] => 2014-12-17 16:31:57
            [Tables] = > Array
                    (
                        [Table_ID] => 1
                        [App_ID] => 1
                        [Table_Name] => Customers
                    ),
                Array
                    (
                        [Table_ID] => 2
                        [App_ID] => 1
                        [Table_Name] => Jobs
                    )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [App_ID] => 2
            [App_Name] => Estimating
            [App_Created] => 2014-12-17 23:49:40
        )
```

)

My Current PHP Code:

```
//Get App List
$apps_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Apps`") or die("Conn Query Apps Failed");
$apps = array();
while($apps = $apps_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $app_id = $apps['App_ID'];
        $table_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Tables` WHERE `App_ID` = $app_id") or die("Conn Query Tables in Apps Failed");
         // My Guess is Something Here? 
        $apps_a[$app_id] = $apps;
}

// Table List
$table_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Tables`") or die("Conn Query Tables Failed");
$tables = array();
while($tables = $table_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $table_id = $tables['Table_ID'];
        $tables_a[$table_id] = $tables;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks cleaner, and faster as you make only 2 queries instead of zillions

```
$apps_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Apps`");
$apps_ids = array();
while ($app = $apps_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $apps_ids[] = $app['App_ID'];
    $apps[$app['App_ID']] = $app;
}

$apps_ids = implode(',', $apps_ids);

$table_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Tables` WHERE IN ({$apps_ids})");

while($table = $table_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $apps[$table['App_ID']]['tables'][] = $table;
}
```

Comment: I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object on line while($table = $table_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))

Comment: Got it changed the line to $table_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Tables` WHERE `App_ID` IN ({$apps_ids})");

Comment: It's All Good, Thank Your for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
$table_id = $tables['Table_ID'];
$tables_a[$table_id] = $tables;
```

into:

```
$apps_a[$tables['App_ID']]['Tables'][$tables['Table_ID']] = $tables;
```